# How to add a border around a GeoTIFF?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, polygon-creation, polygonize

I have a 200x200 GeoTIFF from which I am trying to create multiple polygons. I am using different range values to generate different polygons. However, the inverse of the polygons I want are being generated for some of the range values, possibly because the pixels are hitting the edge of the TIFF. How can I change the TIFF to a 201x201 adding a 1 pixel thick layer around the outside with the extra pixels holding nodata values?

Comment: Use gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html with -te that you can calculate by using the current extent and pixel size. Do you rather want 202x202 pixels?

Comment: 202x202 would be fine. There just needs to be a thin band around the outside of the tif that holds 0 values

Answer (score 2):

You can use gdal.warp to specify the new dimensions, e.g.,

```
gdalwarp.exe -te xmin ymin xmax ymax old_extent.tif new_extent.tif
```